# Create a batch file to run a command with arguments multiple times

Tags: batch-file

I use the following command to export data from a source file to target file in CSV format.

```
C:\MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample.dat" "C:\Test\results.CSV"
```

However I need to repeat the same command multiple times just by changing the source and target files. something like this

```
C:\MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample01.dat" "C:\Test\results01.CSV"
C:\MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample02.dat" "C:\Test\results02.CSV"
C:\MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample03.dat" "C:\Test\results03.CSV"
```

I'm looking to create a batch file to do the job. I have tried the following in a batch file and ran, but it is opening multiple console windows all at the same time. I want all this to happen in just one Command window and run the commands one after the other.

```
cd "C:\Test\" 
start MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample.dat" "C:\Test\results.CSV"
start MyApp.EXE -export "C:\Test\Sample01.dat" "C:\Test\results01.CSV"
```

I want code to create a batch file which runs `MyApp.exe` multiple times with arguments.

I'm using PowerShell to generate the batch file, so I don't need variables in the .bat file.

Comment: Just remove the `start` command

Comment: @MCND - Propose it as an answer.

Comment: Use `call` instead of start.

Comment: "call" worked like a charm. Thanks @jwdonahue

Comment: Trying the command by removing "start" also worked. thanks @MCND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task could be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("C:\Test\Sample*.dat") do (
    set "FileNameCSV=%%~nI"
    set "FileNameCSV=!FileNameCSV:Sample=results!"
    C:\MyApp.exe -export "%%I" "%%~dpI!FileNameCSV!.csv"
)
endlocal
```

Command **FOR** searches in specified directory `C:\Test` for all files matching the wildcard pattern `Sample*.dat`. For each file the fully qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) is assigned to loop variable `I`.

The first command in body command block of **FOR** loop assigns just the file name to environment variable `FileNameCSV`. On this line a DAT file name with one or more exclamation marks would **not** be interpreted as most users expect. The exclamation mark(s) would be interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference. However, this is no problem here according to file names in question.

The second **SET** command line uses a simple case-insensitive string substitution to replace all occurrences of `sample` by `results` in CSV file name.

The environment variable must be referenced with delayed expansion using `!VariableName!` syntax. Otherwise the Windows command line interpreter `cmd.exe` would expand (= replace) the reference of the environment variable on using `%VariableName%` on parsing entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` before **FOR** is executed at all.

The third command line executes your application with the input file name with full path and extension and the CSV file name also with full path of input file, but with modified file name and a different file extension.

But faster would be following batch code also working for files with `!` in fully qualified file name.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("C:\Test\Sample*.dat") do C:\MyApp.exe -export "%%I" "%%~dpI_%%~nI.csv"
ren "C:\Test\_Sample*.csv" "results*.csv"
```

The **FOR** loop executes your application with each `*.dat` as input file and with `_*.csv` as output file, i.e. `_Sample.csv`, `_Sample01.csv`, ...
The CSV files are renamed after finishing processing all DAT files to `results.csv`, `results1.csv`, ...
Adding the additional underscore is necessary to rename all `_Sample*.csv` correct to `results*.csv`. The number of characters before wildcard character `*` must be the same in current and new file name.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

But I do not really understand why all this is done with a batch file executed by Windows command line interpreter `cmd.exe` if this batch file is really created with a PowerShell script executed by script interpreter `powershell.exe`. All this can be done also from within the PowerShell script by using the appropriate PowerShell script functions.